# Not able to run Android Lint tool from Eclipse

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-lint

I tried to run Lint available in the latest Android SDK r16 from Eclipse for my project.
I am getting the error: `Comparison method violates its general contract!`
The full log is here:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.LintList.getMarkers(LintList.java:188)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.LintList.setResources(LintList.java:156)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.LintViewPart.createPartControl(LintViewPart.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:981)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.onActivate(WorkbenchPage.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$27.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:3023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setActivePage(WorkbenchWindow.java:3004)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$20.runWithException(WorkbenchWindow.java:2290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: whats your eclipse version. RU using 3.6 and above right?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Version: 3.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this [Link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22501).
It was a Bug in the Lint tool.  It has been fixed in the latest [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) 16.0.1 release.

Answer (score 2):

right click your android project choose `Android Tools-> Clear Lint Markers`

then again run Lint once.

Comment: can try lint with another project once.

Comment: yea it works with some projects. But for some it shows this error.